# How can I use libx265 (H.265) in the ffmpeg-python package?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

How can I use libx265 ([H.265](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding)) in the ffmpeg-python package?

I tried using:

```
(
    ffmpeg
    .input('0.mp4')
    .filter('fps', fps=25, round='up')
    .output('out.mkv', format='h265')
    .run()
)
```

But it is throwing an error:

> format is not recognized

But this works:

```
(
    ffmpeg
    .input('0.mp4')
    .filter('fps', fps=25, round='up')
    .output('out.mkv', format='h264')
    .run()
)
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344997/how-to-get-a-lossless-encoding-with-ffmpeg-libx265 You can also check out the documentation, section 16.14 https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `format='h265'` with `vcodec='libx265'`.

---

- H.265 is a video codec, and `vcodec='libx265'` tells FFmpeg to use the `libx265` video encoder.
- The output format, in case of an MKV video container is `format='matroska'`.
  You don't have to set the format, because FFmpeg automatically selects the output format by the `.mkv` file extension.

---

Updated code:

```
import ffmpeg

(
    ffmpeg
    .input('0.mp4')
    .filter('fps', fps=25, round='up')
    .output('out.mkv', vcodec='libx265')
    .run()
)
```

Comment: Thankyou! Is it possible to add " -bitexact -map_metadata -1 " in the above code?

Comment: You can add them to the output arguments: `output('out.mkv', vcodec='libx265', fflags='bitexact', map_metadata='-1')`

Comment: It looks like `fflags='bitexact'` is not equivalent to `-bitexact`. A way around it is using `**{'bitexact': None}` (instead of `fflags='bitexact'`).